# How to pass a value to an action in Struts 2 when you don't have a form?

Tags: java, struts2, action-mapping

I've written a submit button like this:

```
<s:submit type="button" value="Delete" action="%{notesDeleteUrl}" theme="simple"/>
```

And I've defined the url like this.

```
<s:url value="notesDeleteAction.action" id="notesDeleteUrl" >
<s:param name="noteId"><s:propertyvalue="iNote" />    </s:param>                                   
</s:url>
```

So basically, I have no < s:form > tag on my JSP but I need to call an action with the submit button while passing a value to it. And I get this error.

- There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [notesDeleteAction?noteId=48] associated with context path [/abc].

So I understand that it's unable to resolve the action because of the added parameter, but how else can I send this value to the action?

Comment: A submit without a form is non-sensical. Use a styled link.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is nothing to do with the parameter. Struts doesn't know what to do with the URL /notesDeleteAction

You'll need to include the action in your struts.xml file:

```
<package name="yourpackage" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="notesDeleteAction" class="foo.YourClass">
    <result>somepage.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

There are 2 ways to get the parameter in your class, foo.YourClass

One way is:

```
Map parameters = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
```

The other way is for you class to implement org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ParameterAware